# How can I use splash potions to teleport players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to teleport a thrown splash potion to an entity/player on 1.12? I'm using Bukkit, so some commands might be different.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: yes @Frank I have

Comment: Okay, so show us what you've tried.  Just saying you have doesn't really help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

A thrown potion has the object ID "potion". So for example, to teleport the nearest potion to the nearest player, use `/tp @e[type=potion,c=1] @p`